# open of popup on click of gridview linkbutton

Tags: asp.net

I have Gridview and ,it consists of 3 columns , the 1st column is of ID,2nd of date and 3rd of description.
the 1st column ID's are all linkbutton and when i click the linkbutton a popup window has to open.
and the text of the linkbutton should be populated in the textbox of popup window. plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Add a hyperlink column to your grid view, pass the text as query string to the pop up page, don't forget to set target property to _blank.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="AnyText" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Page.aspx?text={0}" 
                DataTextField="AnyText" HeaderText="Test" Target="_blank" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On page.aspx you need to place a textbox then in page load event add:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["text"];
}
```

Hope this is what are you looking for.